# How to connect to oauth1 service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth

I try to authenticate the user of my web app with Trello, which uses oauth1 authentication. The [oauth library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth)   recommended in their [demo project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/trello-oauth) does not seem to have typings. What is the best alternative to authenticate my app with Trello:

- Is there any Typescript based oauth1 library I missed while googling?
- Is it better to use the library and not care about type safety or implement the oauth authorization flow myself?

Answer (score 0):

For most of the popular JS libraries user created type definitions can be found at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). You can find type definitions for your oauth library here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/oauth.

If your library is not widely used and there are no type definitions yet, it is recommended to write your own type definitions for the publicly facing interfaces.

In general, it is best not to implement standardized auth flows such as oauth yourself but to leverage existing solutions.